# Undefined variable in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, undefined

I'm creating a user registration form. I create a form in the Component. when the user registers he redirects to the user page where he sees all users. when he wanted to edit or update something from in his details he redirects to the same registration form page but this will be a new URL and new Title. I'm getting an undefined variable $title and $url error. when I pass data from the controller to view I get this error.

Registration Form Controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $url = url('/register'); 
    $title = ("Registration Form");
    $data = compact( 'url');
    return view('RegistrationForm')->with($data);
}

public function store (Request $request)
{

    $request->validate(
        [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password|min:8',
            'address' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required',
            'tearms_and_conditions' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'firstname.required' => 'Please enter your First Name',
            'lastname.required' => 'Please nter your Last Name',
            'email.required' => 'Please enter an Email',
            'password.required' => 'Please Enter a Password'
        ],
    );

    $users = new Users;
    $users->firstname = $request['firstname'];
    $users->lastname = $request['lastname'];
    $users->email = $request['email'];
    $users->password = md5($request['password']);
    $users->address = $request['address'];
    $users->country = $request['country'];
    $users->state = $request['state'];
    $users->city = $request['city'];
    $users->gender = $request['gender'];
    $users->date_of_birth = $request['date_of_birth'];
    $users->save();

    return redirect('/register/view');
}

public function view (Request $request)
{
    $users = Users::all();
    $data = compact('users');
    return view('user-view')->with($data);
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $user = Users::find($id);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($user);
    die;
    return redirect('/register/view');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = Users::find($id);
    if (is_null($user)) 
    {
        return redirect('/register/view');
    }
    else 
    {
        $url = url("user/update"."/". $id);
        $title = "Update Details";
        $data = compact('user', 'url', 'title');
        return redirect('/register')->with($data);
    }
}

public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = Users::find($id);
    $users->firstname = $request['firstname'];
    $users->lastname = $request['lastname'];
    $users->email = $request['email'];
    $users->address = $request['address'];
    $users->country = $request['country'];
    $users->state = $request['state'];
    $users->city = $request['city'];
    $users->gender = $request['gender'];
    $users->date_of_birth = $request['date_of_birth'];
    $users->save();

    return redirect('register/view');
}
```

}

Route

```
Route::get('/register', [RegistrationFormController::class, 'index']);
```

View

```
<body>
<h1> {{$title}} </h1> 
<x-registration-form-component :country="$country" :url="$url" />
```

RegisreationFormComponent

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `$data` variable as the second argument of the `view()` method:

```
public function index ()
{
    $url = url('/register');
    $title = "Registration Form";
    $data = compact('title', 'url');
    return view('RegistrationForm', $data);
}
```

Comment: Its also not working.

Answer (score -1):

First, to answer your question:

When you use the compact method, you are placing those values in an array. You would need to call them like so:

```php
{{ $data['title'] }}
{{ $data['url'] }}
```

However, you could clean the code up a little bit like this:

```php
public function index()
{
  return view('RegistrationForm', [
    'url' => url('/register'),
    'title' => 'Registration Form',
  ]);
}
```

You can then use them in the blade file like so:

```php
{{ $url }}
{{ $title }}
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: Are you still getting an undefined variable error, or something else now?

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you unwrap the string from those parentheses? It should be $title = “”; not $title = (“”);

Comment: Also, you changed the source code from your original question. Which method are you talking about now? What is the route you are getting the error on?